TikZ/PGF: how to execute .code{} when the shape is initialized
I am trying to figure out how to declare a PGF shape with an "optional" part, but I am running into trouble with initial values vs. key/value pairs. I have created a minimal working example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifdetonatorpresent
\def\detonatortype{whew!}
\pgfkeys{%
  /pgf/detonator/.is if=detonatorpresent,
  /pgf/detonator/.initial=false,
  /pgf/detonator type/.is choice,
  /pgf/detonator type/.initial=plunger,
  /pgf/detonator type/plunger/.code={
    \def\detonatortype{caution!}
  },
  /pgf/detonator type/hair/.code={
    \def\detonatortype{BOOM!}
  },
}
\pgfdeclareshape{bomb}{%
  \nodeparts{text}
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}%
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]%
  \behindbackgroundpath{
    \ifdetonatorpresent
      \pgftext{\detonatortype}
    \fi
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[bomb,detonator] (Test1) at (0,0) {};
\node[bomb,detonator,detonator type=plunger] (Test2) at (0,-1) {};
\node[bomb,detonator,detonator type=hair] (Test2) at (0,-2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The first node should look exactly like the second node, but it is not executing the code for "plunger" unless I explicitly give detonator type=plunger in the node definition. Ideally, line 4 (the "external" definition of \detonatortype) should not be necessary, either.
What am I doing wrong and/or what is the "right" way to do this?

.initial doesn't specify some first value the key gets (for that just do <key>=<value> as usual) but it initializes a value-key with the given value. You can basically define two keys with the same name: once as a value-key (a key that holds a value) and once as a code-key (a key that executes stuff). Usually, if you have a code-key, you don't want it to be a value-key as well and vice versa. Just do detonator type=plunger and you primed \detonatortype successfully.

EDIT: with
/tikz/detonator/.style={
    /pgf/detonator,
    /pgf/detonator type
    },

Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifdetonatorpresent
\def\detonatortype{whew!}
\pgfkeys{%
  /pgf/detonator/.is if=detonatorpresent,
  /pgf/detonator/.initial=false,
  /pgf/detonator type/.is choice,
  /pgf/detonator type/.default=plunger,
  /pgf/detonator type/plunger/.code={
    \def\detonatortype{caution!}
  },
  /pgf/detonator type/hair/.code={
    \def\detonatortype{BOOM!}
  },
  /tikz/detonator/.style={
    /pgf/detonator,
    /pgf/detonator type
    },
}
\pgfdeclareshape{bomb}{%
  \nodeparts{text}
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}%
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]%
  \behindbackgroundpath{
    \ifdetonatorpresent
      \pgftext{\detonatortype}
    \fi
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[bomb,detonator] (Test1) at (0,0) {};
\node[bomb,detonator,detonator type=plunger] (Test2) at (0,-1) {};
\node[bomb,detonator,detonator type=hair] (Test2) at (0,-2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Old answer
The default is for detonator type.
With \node[bomb,detonator] (Test1) at (0,0) {}; the key detonator type/.code is not executed . \detonatortypeis whew!
If you want default value of detonator type
/pgf/detonator type/.default=plunger,

and
\node[bomb,detonator,detonator type]

This post can help you PGF Keys differences between .initial and .default
simplified code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
% \usepackage{tikz}
\def\detonatortype{whew!}
\pgfkeys{%
  /pgf/detonator type/.is choice, 
  /pgf/detonator type/plunger/.code={
    \def\detonatortype{plunger}
  },
  /pgf/detonator type/hair/.code={
    \def\detonatortype{hair}
  },
  /pgf/detonator type/.default=plunger,
  % /pgf/detonator type/.initial=plunger,
}

\begin{document}
\detonatortype

\pgfkeys{/pgf/detonator type}%<-- default value
\detonatortype

\pgfkeys{/pgf/detonator type=hair}
\detonatortype

\pgfkeys{/pgf/detonator type}
\detonatortype
\end{document}



This only works if the user explicitly adds "detonator type" to the \node definition. I am trying to get the default in the specific (more complicated...) case to be that if the user simply specified \node [bomb] it would produce a bomb with a detonator of the default type without having to specify that it should have a detonator or that it should have a detonator type. Is this possible?

I found one solution, there is surely better. See the edit answer

This did not solve my problem directly, but it led me to try something else (in this example, eliminating the detonator type key entirely and just making detonator a code key that automatically sets the boolean if it is called). Thanks.
